# Jobs in a queue is dropped unexpectedly in Gearman

Tags: queue, gearman

I'm dealing with a very strange problem now.

Since I queue the jobs over 1,000 at once, Gearman doesn't work properly so far...

The problem is that, when I reserve the jobs in background mode, I could see the jobs were correctly queued from the monitoring page (gearman monitor),
but It is drained right after without delivering it to the worker. (within a few seconds)
After all, the jobs never be executed by the worker, just disappeared from the queue (job server).

So I tried rebooting the server entirely, and reinstall gearman as well as php library. (I'm using 1 CentOS, 1 Ubuntu with PHP gearman library, and version is 0.34 and 1.0.2)
But no luck yet... Job server just misbehaving as I explained in aobve.

What should I do for now?
Can I check the workers state, or see and monitor the whole process from queueing the jobs to the delivering to the worker?
When I tried gearmand with a option like: 'gearmand -vvvv' It never print anything on the screen while I register worker to the server, and run a job with client code (PHP)

Any comment will be appreciated.

For your information, I'm not considering persistent queue using MySQL or SQLite for now, because it sometimes occurs performance issue with slow execution.

Comment: That would happen if you're not using persistent queues and a channel that added a job (producer) disconnects. Is that the case? Gearman has default settings for 2m jobs in queue and supports up to 4bn, so 1k should not be a a problem.

Comment: I think that's the case I've encountered. Now I solved those problems by adopting MySQL as a persistent queue. Thanks